# Conditional navigation in fragment only triggers once

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

With most and/or all of my Android development knowledge coming from Google's course on Udacity about developing android apps with Kotlin, I have run into an issue where my conditional navigation only triggers once, and any further triggers lock up the app in a loop.

Hopefully there is enough info here to avoid the XY problem. It also may be too verbose, as I was trying to rubber duck into the text box to see if I could notice any glaring issues.

The application is a single activity application, which uses android architecture components, databinding, and the navigation library. It also uses the Android AWS SDK, but I don't believe that is relevant to the issue.

Following Google's navigation principles, the fixed start destination is
not the login screen.

Login screen is conditional on the sign in state
from AWSMobileClient being true.

**Application Class**

AWSMobileClient is initialized in class extending Application

```
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(applicationContext, object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {

            override fun onResult(userStateDetails: UserStateDetails) {
                Timber.i("Inside init function onResult: %s", userStateDetails.userState)

            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e, "Initialization error.")
            }
        }
        )
```

**Home Screen ViewModel**

Checks the sign in state, and sets a MutableLiveData with that boolean value

```
 private var _isSignedIn = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    val isSignedIn: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isSignedIn


    init {
        startup()
    }

    private fun startup() {

        Timber.i(
            "Startup isSignedIn state: %s",
            AWSMobileClient.getInstance()?.isSignedIn.toString()
        )

        _isSignedIn.value = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().isSignedIn


    }

    fun logout() {
        Timber.i("Trying to logout now..")
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signOut()
        _isSignedIn.value = false
    }
```

**Home Screen Fragment**

```
        Timber.i("Viewmodel in oncreate")
        val homeScreenViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(HomeScreenViewModel::class.java)


        binding.homeScreenViewModel = homeScreenViewModel

        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

        val navController = findNavController()


        homeScreenViewModel.isSignedIn.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { signIn ->
            if (signIn) {
                Timber.i("ifTrue isSignedIn")
                homeScreenViewModel.apiCall()
            }
            else {
                navController.navigate(HomeScreenFragmentDirections.actionHomeScreenFragmentToLoginFragment())
                Timber.i("Else isSignedIn")
            }
        })
```

***Clean install of App***

Logcat

```
2019-07-03 15:30:38.727 I/AWSKeyValueStore: Creating the AWSKeyValueStore with key for sharedPreferences = CognitoIdentityProviderCache
2019-07-03 15:30:38.752 I/ExampleApplication$onCreate: Inside init function onResult: SIGNED_OUT
2019-07-03 15:30:38.759 I/HomeScreenFragment: Viewmodel in oncreate
2019-07-03 15:30:38.759 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Startup isSignedIn state: false
2019-07-03 15:30:38.778 I/HomeScreenFragment$onCreateView: Else isSignedIn
2019-07-03 15:30:39.182 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onStop
```

At this point, the app is sitting on the login screen, all working as expected.

It

-Launched to homescreen fragment

-Checked my sign in state, sees I am not signed in,

-Navigates me to login screen.

Logcat after logging in

```
2019-07-03 15:33:39.605 I/LoginViewModel$signIn: Sign-in callback state: DONE
2019-07-03 15:33:39.605 I/LoginViewModel$signIn: Sign-in done.
2019-07-03 15:33:39.611 I/HomeScreenFragment: Viewmodel in oncreate
2019-07-03 15:33:39.618 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Startup isSignedIn state: true
2019-07-03 15:33:39.626 I/HomeScreenFragment$onCreateView: ifTrue isSignedIn
2019-07-03 15:33:39.628 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onResume
2019-07-03 15:33:39.635 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Viewmodel onCleared
2019-07-03 15:33:39.635 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onDestroy
```

I successfully login, am navigated back to homescreen, my sign in state is checked,
sees I am signed in, it fetches data from an api, and displays that in
a recyclerview.

I am not sure why the fragment/viewmodel are cleared/destroyed. Fragment is
still on screen and can interact with it.

When I hit the sign out button on homescreen fragment, the logout function is called from the viewmodel

and at this point, the app locks up and my logcat is this, repeated to infinity

```
2019-07-03 15:40:39.756 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Trying to logout now..
2019-07-03 15:40:39.779 I/HomeScreenFragment$onCreateView: Else isSignedIn
2019-07-03 15:40:39.834 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onPause
2019-07-03 15:40:39.835 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onStop
2019-07-03 15:40:39.837 I/HomeScreenFragment: Viewmodel in oncreate
2019-07-03 15:40:39.838 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Startup isSignedIn state: false
2019-07-03 15:40:39.840 I/HomeScreenFragment$onCreateView: Else isSignedIn
2019-07-03 15:40:39.840 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onResume
2019-07-03 15:40:39.840 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Viewmodel onCleared
2019-07-03 15:40:39.841 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onDestroy
```

If I kill the app and relaunch it, it pops up to the login screen, as expected.

**Launching app when I am already signed in**

If I launch the app and am already signed in, I stay at the homescreen fragment.
When I click the sign out button, I am signed out and navigated to the login screen.

```
2019-07-03 15:43:40.417 I/ExampleApplication$onCreate: Inside init function onResult: SIGNED_IN
2019-07-03 15:43:40.438 I/HomeScreenFragment: Viewmodel in oncreate
2019-07-03 15:43:40.447 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Startup isSignedIn state: true
2019-07-03 15:43:40.485 I/HomeScreenFragment$onCreateView: ifTrue isSignedIn
2019-07-03 15:43:40.650 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onResume
2019-07-03 15:43:40.835 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-07-03 15:43:40.835 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-07-03 15:43:45.086 I/HomeScreenViewModel: Trying to logout now..
2019-07-03 15:43:45.115 I/HomeScreenFragment$onCreateView: Else isSignedIn
2019-07-03 15:43:45.676 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onPause
2019-07-03 15:43:45.676 I/HomeScreenFragment: Homescreen fragment onStop
2019-07-03 15:43:45.758 I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=27KB, data=29KB
2019-07-03 15:43:45.759 I/art: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=28KB
2019-07-03 15:43:45.759 I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

I can login at this point, and am correctly navigated back to the homescreen.
Clicking the signout button will lock the app until it is killed and relaunched.

So it seems to me that as long as it is the first time the observer sees the signIn value being false,
it will correctly navigate me to the login screen and back. If it is the second time, however,
the app locks up.

EDIT:

requested methods

```
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Timber.i("Homescreen fragment onPause")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Timber.i("Homescreen fragment onStop")

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Timber.i("Homescreen fragment onResume")

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Timber.i("Homescreen fragment onDestroy")

    }
```

Comment: Could you add your homescreen onresume/onstart code

Comment: The only things on the various lifecycle calls are log messages stating they are called.